# Android - How to design Sliding menu like designed in FIFA Official iPhone app

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I've searched a lot on Google for following design but all I end up is [Navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html), which is little bit different then the below one. I've taken this screenshot from [FIFA Official iPhone App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fifa-official-app/id756904853?mt=8)

How to design sliding menu like below one in Android

[image: Fifa Offical iPhone app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a bit late for user7055, but I've found a project called [AndroidResideMenu](https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu) on Github which seems to achieve what is asked here.

Hope this help other people : )

Answer (score 0):

You could use the NavigationDrawer lib from google ;) there are several tutorials for that

Comment: Google Navigation drawer is not like the above one, Its design is much different.

Comment: Check this link which you are saying : http://developer.android.com/design/media/navigation_drawer_overview.png

Comment: I don't know the FIFA app but i'm sure that you can do the same with it.. you can edit the xml and design it like the fifa app. I have a app with such a navigation drawer and you can do what ever you want to do with that. As i know there are noch tutorial how to design such a modern/cool slide ou navigation but it is possible

Comment: Can't you see the difference ? The screen becomes too small on right side, but Navigation drawer didn't decrease screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56413/discussion-between-user7055-and-tobias).